# Creating a somewhat complicated cartesian result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called "where_clauses" which contains a bunch of conditions I would like to use for building dynamic queries. I would like to know all possible queries I could perform using this data. Here is my "where_clauses" data...

```
INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (1,'x','x < 1');
INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (2,'x','x < 2');
INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (3,'x','x < 3');
INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (4,'y','y < 1');
INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (5,'y','y < 2');
INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (6,'y','y < 3');
INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (7,'z','z < 1');
```

Ideally I would like the "all possible queries" in the form of an array of ids. For example, the "all possible queries" result would be...

```
{1}
{1,4}
{1,4,7}
{1,5}
{1,5,7}
{1,6}
{1,6,7}
{2}
{2,4}
{2,4,7}
{2,5}
{2,5,7}
{2,6}
{2,6,7}
{3}
{3,4}
{3,4,7}
{3,5}
{3,5,7}
{3,6}
{3,6,7}
{4}
{4,7}
{5}
{5,7}
{6}
{6,7}
{7}
```

Note that im throwing out joining on equal columns. What is a query that would give all possible where_clauses?

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of problem that the [new](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) `WITH RECURSIVE` is intended to solve. The following generalizes to any number of column names (not just `x`, `y`, `z`).

```
WITH RECURSIVE subq(a, x) AS
  ( VALUES (ARRAY[]::int[], NULL) /* initial */
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT subq.a || id, col_name FROM subq JOIN where_clauses
    ON x IS NULL OR x < col_name )
SELECT a FROM subq 
WHERE x IS NOT NULL;  /* discard the initial empty array */
```

Comment: Excellent. This looks like what I need. To take it one step further, let's say I add in the clauses INSERT INTO where_clauses (id,col_name,clause) VALUES (8,'x','x > 1');. How could I refactor this query so that I could also get... {3,5,7,8}?

Comment: Because it's a greater than, it's independent of 1, 2, and 3, right? If all your constraints are going to be inequalities, I think I would get rid of `clause` and have columns `col_name`, `op`, and `value` (just the number). When you need to, in later queries, you can reconstruct the clause by concatenating these fields together. Now instead of sorting just on `col_name`, use the concatenation `col_name||op` as the `x` in the subquery. Is this clear?

Comment: Cool, i've done that so far. I have your previous recursive query working now on the col_name, op, and value fields by concatenating the col_name||op fields. Now I just need to figure out how to ensure im not including the superflous ranges. Ie: WHERE x > 2 AND x > 1. Is that going to take a lot of case statements?

Comment: @NickBoutelier Your SQL optimizer will almost certainly do that for you. ORMs generate redundant clauses in automatic SQL generation all the time. You can extend the ordering to the `value` column. I'll leave that as an exercise, but it won't handle `x < 2 AND x > 3` with its mixed operators. But unless you have an aesthetic reason, I wouldn't bother, not even to handle cases that evaluate to `FALSE` like the one I just gave.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it selects three columns, those that are not used for a clause are left NULL, you could concatenate or manipulate that result further:

```
--all possibilities with only one clause
SELECT
    id AS ID1, NULL ID2, NULL AS ID3
  FROM where_clauses
--all possibilities with two clauses (xy,xz,yz)
UNION
SELECT
    WC1.id AS ID1, WC2.id AS ID2, NULL AS ID3
  FROM where_clauses WC1
  CROSS JOIN where_clauses WC2
  WHERE
    WC1.col_name != WC2.col_name
    AND WC1.id > WC2.id
--all possibilities with an x and a y and a z clause
UNION
SELECT
    WC1.id AS ID1, WC2.id AS ID2, WC3.id AS ID3
  FROM where_clauses WC1
  CROSS JOIN where_clauses WC2
  CROSS JOIN where_clauses WC3
  WHERE
    WC1.col_name != WC2.col_name
    AND WC1.id > WC2.id

    AND WC1.col_name != WC3.col_name
    AND WC1.id > WC3.id

    AND WC2.col_name != WC3.col_name
    AND WC2.id > WC3.id
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7e0df/22) is a fiddle.

EDIT: modified fiddle slightly

Comment: What would this look like with columns named a-z instead of just x-z?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT string_to_array(TRIM(x || ',' || y || ',' || z, ','), ',')
FROM (
WITH sq AS (
    SELECT a.id x, b.id y, c.id z
    FROM where_clauses a, where_clauses b, where_clauses c
    WHERE a.col_name != b.col_name AND
          a.col_name != c.col_name AND
          b.col_name != c.col_name AND
          a.id < b.id AND
          b.id < c.id
)
SELECT x, y, z FROM sq
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct x, y, null::int FROM sq
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct y, z, null::int FROM sq
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct x, null::int, null::int FROM sq
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct y, null::int, null::int FROM sq
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct z, null::int, null::int FROM sq
) ORDER BY 1;
```

Does above query helps you out ?

Comment: What would this look like with columns named a-z instead of just x-z?